# "В честь твоего день рождения" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Насколько я знаю, правильно говорить "В честь твоего дня рождения".

*Можно ли сказать "В честь твоего **день** рождения"?*

Comment: Ошибки возникают в том случае, если "день рождения" понимается как неразложимое сочетание, и поэтому первое слово не склоняют: на моем "день рождении" и т.д. Но это свободное словосочетание, в котором склоняются оба слова.

Comment: Возможно, под влиянием английского, в котором "день" и "рождение" слились в одно слово birthday, возможно, по какой-то другой причине, но приходится слышать (но только устно) такое: "твое деньрождение" и соответственно "в честь твоего деньрождения". Но это очень грубая ошибка.

Answer (score 5):

**в честь**
***кого-чего***, *в зн. предлога*. В знак уважения, почтения, в память.
(Словарь многих выражений, 2014)

Правильно только ТАК: ***В честь твоего дня рождения***.

*Я испортил вечеринку-сюрприз в честь твоего **дня** рождения...*
*И сегодня, в честь твоего **дня** рождения, по всему Королевству полетят лепестки белых роз, чтобы каждый житель мог порадоваться с нами.*
*Это паучок счастья, Агата, паучок счастья в честь твоего **дня** рождения.*

Можно привести примеры склонения и других "особых" дней.
В честь: дня свадьбы, дня бракосочетания, дня ангела, дня матери, дня памяти...
(Никто никогда не скажет "в честь твоего день свадьбы"!)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: В честь твоего дня рождения.

В Честь предл. с род.
1.
Употребляется при указании на кого-либо или на что-либо, в знак уважения, почтения к которым производится какое-либо действие.

См.: Толковый словарь Ефремовой.